# Unable to change the default pose of human actors when using talk_a.dae or talk_b.dae

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Below is a section of my code:

-2 -4 0.2 0 0 1.57

talk_a.dae
1.0


talk_a.dae

I am using Gazebo 9. I would like to load this actor at a specified pose but the pose does not seem to be applied even if I specify in the code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25351/unable-to-change-the-default-pose-of-human-actors-when-using-talk_a.dae-or-talk_b.dae/) by [PKGosal](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28200/pkgosal/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is not ideal, but one trick is to also add a `<script><trajectory>` with 2 waypoints that have the same pose. [Here's an example](https://github.com/osrf/citysim/blob/3928b08e2598f5ead2e9b24640fe1bde262a136d/worlds/simple_city.world#L13761-L13786):

```
  <actor name="talkingA">
    <pose>5 5 5.76 0 0 0</pose>
    <skin>
      <filename>model://actor/meshes/SKIN_man_blue_shirt.dae</filename>
    </skin>
    <animation name="animation">
      <filename>model://actor/meshes/ANIMATION_talking_a.dae</filename>
      
    </animation>
      <script>
        <trajectory id="0" type="animation">
          
            <waypoint>
              <time>100</time>
              <pose>5 5 5.16 0 0 0</pose>
            </waypoint>
          
            <waypoint>
              <time>100</time>
              <pose>5 5 5.16 0 0 0</pose>
            </waypoint>
          
        </trajectory>
      </script>
  </actor>
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKGosal](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28200/pkgosal/) on 2020-06-20**:
Thanks a lot! That works for me for now.